# How define today date with Default timestmp

Tags: postgresql, date, time

I am using postgressql i wish to get  the data for currentdate, i want filter the data based on the date
in data base my plandate filed is define as `Time stamp with time zone` so its showing like this format  `2013-09-01 03:22:01.438348+05:30` my query is like this

```
 select ttodoid ,date,details from ttodo where date=currentdate():
```

but currentdate function giving me just date '2013-10-06' based on this result is no rows how can i manage it for today date detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED:** One way to do it

```
SELECT *
  FROM ttodo
 WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC('day', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
                AND DATE_TRUNC('day', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
                  + INTERVAL '1 DAY' 
                  - INTERVAL '1 MICROSECOND';
```

or

```
SELECT * 
  FROM ttodo
 WHERE date >= DATE_TRUNC('day', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
   AND date <  DATE_TRUNC('day', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
             + INTERVAL '1 DAY';
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/a166b/8)** demo

Comment: This is (kind-of) wrong. You can, with this approach, get a record that is of tomorrow if, and only if, its time part is `'00:00:00.000'` (mid night, exactly). To avoid that you should `date_trunc` on the `date` field or use `>=` and `<` (not inclusive) instead of between (which is `>=` and `<=`).

Comment: @MatheusOl Absolutely valid point. Thanks for the input. Answer and sqlfiddle updated. *It was too late and was answering in a hurry.*

Comment: don't worry it happens... But if you want to be more (really more) precise, you should use `- INTERVAL '1 microsecond'` (instead of `millisecond`), then I'll have nothing else to complain, =P.

Answer (score 0):

select * from ttodo where (ttodo.todoplandate::date = current_date)  or
           (ttodo.todoplandate::date < current_date

Comment: Why the second verification?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easier approach would be just to convert your field to `date`:

```
SELECT ttodoid ,date,details FROM ttodo
WHERE CAST(date AS DATE) = current_date;
```

Notice that, ff you want this query to be indexed, you have to create the index with the cast:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_ttodo_date ON ttodo ((CAST(date AS DATE)));
```

Another approach, is instead of casting the field, is checking the intervals, something similar of what [petern proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218774/how-define-today-date-with-default-timestmp/19219098#19219098), but with correct intervals:

```
SELECT ttodoid ,date,details FROM ttodo
WHERE date >= date_trunc('day', current_timestamp)
      AND date < (date_trunc('day', current_timestamp) + interval '1day');
```

This approach has the advantage that it can use an index on the `date` field only, which is good if you already have it.